# Two similar tables but different join performances

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

I am running the exact same join query using two different tables, but the first one (table A) times out whereas the second (table B) does not.

```
SELECT * FROM table_X
INNER JOIN table_A
ON table_A.point_origin = table_X.item_id
WHERE ROWNUM < 10;

SELECT * FROM table_X
INNER JOIN table_B
ON table_B.point_origin = table_X.item_id
WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
```

As far as I know, table A is a subset of table B. Neither table A nor table B have point_origin indexed.

(Edit for clarification: table A is a only a subset of table B in terms of row identifiers, not in terms of exact column data.)

For what it's worth, I'm dealing with very large tables and item_id is indexed.

Is there anything else that would affect performance here or am I definitely wrong about some information provided?

Edit: Additional information per a comment below

table_A:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                     |     9 |  4743 |    12   (0)|       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |                     |       |       |            |       |       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table_X             |     1 |   227 |     1   (0)|       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS              |                     |    11 |  5797 |    12   (0)|       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ALL      |                     |    10M|  2969M|     2   (0)|     1 |     4 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | table_A             |    10M|  2969M|     2   (0)|     1 |     4 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN         | table_X_IP_PK       |     1 |       |     1   (0)|       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<10)
   6 - access("table_A"."POINT_ORIGIN"="table_X"."ITEM_ID")

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version
```

table_B:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                     |     9 |  3879 |    11   (0)|
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |                     |       |       |            |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table_X             |     1 |   227 |     1   (0)|
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS              |                     |    10 |  4310 |    11   (0)|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | table_B             |   118M|    22G|     2   (0)|
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN         | table_X_IP_PK       |     1 |       |     1   (0)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<10)
   5 - access("table_B"."POINT_ORIGIN"="table_X"."ITEM_ID")

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version
```

Comment: You should check the execution plans of both queries.

Comment: So it looks like table_A does not time out (it would time out with company tools, but I just need to wait a bit when using SQL developer)

Comment: This is my first exposure to execution plans, so forgive me if I'm unclear. table_A lists an extra operation (partition range all) as well as two extra columns (Pstart and Pstop). 

The number of nested loops is the same, but when it comes to table access full:
There are 10M rows and 2969M Bytes for table_A.
There are 121M rows and 23G Bytes for table_B.

What am I supposed to get from this information? I know this may be beyond the scope of this question, but do you have an initial observation from this information that you can provide?

The CPU % is fairly similar between both tables

Comment: @Azianese It might help if you ran `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` for both SQL statements, and added the text execution plans to the question.  But performance questions are difficult on Stack Overflow - a lot of information may be required to solve a complex problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions. Added the execution plans. 

I'm manually changing the table names to fit my initial post description. Please let me know if there seems to be an inconsistency in my table names.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `table_a` is partitioned and that the query only needs to scan 4 partitions while `table_b` is not partitioned and must be read in its entirety.  The optimizer estimates that 4 partitions of `table_a` have 10 million rows while `table_b` has 118 million rows.  You're using a nested loop so you'd expect O(n) performance so based on the statistics, it would make sense that the second query would take ~11.8 times as long as the first query.

Are the optimizer's estimates accurate?  The optimizer is only as good as the statistics you've given it and it is possible that one or both tables have stale statistics.